# Automatically update smartdiagram texts with crossreferences

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning

I want to put a `\smartdiagram` at the begining of some description processes. The diagrams should include the texts corresponding to the title labeled of some sections of this processes. The idea is to modify only the section titles in order to update the diagram texts automatically.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode


\documentclass{report}    
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}

\section{titlesection1}\label{tit:titlesection1}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
\section{titlesection2}\label{tit:titlesection2}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
\section{titlesection3}\label{tit:titlesection3}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...

\smartdiagram[circular diagram:clockwise]{...,...,...} %<<--this should be the clockwise diagram with section names

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\ref` didn't work ?

Comment: when I use `\ref` the result is the number of the labeled section, not the title

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `nameref`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{nameref}

\begin{document}

\section{titlesection1}\label{tit:titlesection1}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
\section{titlesection2}\label{tit:titlesection2}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
\section{titlesection3}\label{tit:titlesection3}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...

\begin{center}
\smartdiagramset{text width=3cm}
\smartdiagram[circular diagram:clockwise]{%
  \nameref{tit:titlesection1},
  \nameref{tit:titlesection2},
  \nameref{tit:titlesection3}
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]